# Set location of reference list/ bibliography in a quarto book chapter

Tags: yaml, quarto, bibliography

I'm creating a quarto book with different chapters. Each chapter has its own reference list, from the same .bib file. The YAML section for the references looks as follows:

```
filters: 
  - section-bibliographies
reference-section-title: References
bibliography: references.bib
```

Most chapters have a 'supplementary material' section and the reference list is placed at the end of each chapter, but I would like to specify its position (so it is placed before the supplementary material).

So currently the chapters look like this:

introduction-
methods-
results-
discussion-
supplementary material-
references

But I would like it to look like this:

introduction-
methods-
results-
discussion-
references-
supplementary material

Is it possible to change the order and have the references before the supplementary material?

---

Example code:

## Title of my project

### Introduction

text text text

### Methods

text text text

### Results

text text text

### Discussion

text text text

### Supplementary information

even more text

Comment: Can provide some example code for a chapter with supplementary material?

Comment: @shafee; thanks, I'm not sure how much the example code add but I've added it to my original question.